# Why is ggplot ignoring my factor levels when I subset my data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using some code I got from an answer to a previous question, but I ran into a funny problem and Id like some expert insight into what is going on. I am trying to plot monthly deviations from an annual mean using bar charts. Specifically I am coloring the different bars different colors depending on whether the monthly mean is above or below the annual mean. I am using the `txhousing` dataset, which is included with the `ggplot2` package.

I thought I could use a factor to denote whether or not this is the case. The months are correctly ordered when I only plot a subset of the data (the "lower" values, but when I add another plot, `ggplot` rearranges all of the months to be alphabetical. Does anyone know why this happens, and what a workaround would be?

Thank you so much for any input! Criticism of my code is welcome :)

*Reproducible Examples*

*1. Using just one plot*

```
library(tidyverse)

# subset txhousing to just years >= 2011, and calculate nested means and dates
housing_df <- filter(txhousing, year == 2014) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(monthly_mean = mean(sales, na.rm = TRUE),
            date = first(date)) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb, ordered = TRUE),
         salesdiff = monthly_mean - mean(monthly_mean), # monthly deviation
         higherlower = case_when(salesdiff >= 0 ~ "higher",                                   
                                 salesdiff < 0 ~ "lower"))

ggplot(data = housing_df, aes(x = month, y = salesdiff, higherlower)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(housing_df, higherlower == "higher"), aes(y = salesdiff, fill = higherlower)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("higher" = "blue", "lower" = "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") # remove legend
```

[image]

*2. Using two plots with all of the data:*

```
ggplot(data = housing_df, aes(x = month, y = salesdiff, higherlower)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(housing_df, higherlower == "higher"), aes(y = salesdiff, fill = higherlower)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(housing_df, higherlower == "lower"), aes(y = salesdiff, fill = higherlower)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("higher" = "blue", "lower" = "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") # remove legend
```

[image]

Comment: I'm just speculating here, because you haven't provided something completely reproducible, but when you use two separate layers, with filtered data, ggplot doesn't know that they came from the same data set. For all it knows, it comes from two totally random data sets. And the set of months in each subset is different, so it no longer "knows" how they fit together. I'm not really sure why you aren't just using one `geom_col` and mapping fill to your variable.

Comment: txhousing is actually an included dataset with the ggplot package. thank you for your comment though. I don't quite understand but I will spend as much time as I can thinking about it!

Comment: Why are you plotting `geom_col()` twice like that? `ggplot(data = housing_df, aes(x = month, y = salesdiff, fill = higherlower)) + geom_col()` should produce what you want (if you add the three other lines you have as well).

Comment: Didn't know that was included, sorry about that. As I suspected, `ggplot(data = housing_df, aes(x = month, y = salesdiff, fill = higherlower)) +
 geom_col()` seems to work just fine. I wasn't sure if it would be able to stitch the factor levels back together again, but it seems not. I always have to try and see.

Comment: (Also, you don't need an ordered factor, just setting the factor levels in a particular order is sufficient.)

Comment: Oh thank you so much for that info @joran! If you are willing to copy and paste those comments into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it! I understand if you do not want to though, as I cannot upvote yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this but I find it a bit of a hit and trial. You are already doing the most common fix which is t convert month into a factor and that's why the first plot works. Why does it not work in the 2nd case is a bit of a mystery but try adding `+ scale_x_discrete(limits= housing_df$month)` to override the x axis order and see if that works.

I agree to the other comments that the best way would be not even use the extra layer as its not needed in this specific case but the above solution works even when there are multiple layers.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, `+ scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` also overrides potentially different factor levels from different data sources in your ggplot.

This topic is also addressed here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/577